# Can it be done ? wordpress + nginx+ https for one page

Tags: css, wordpress, ssl, nginx

I am trying to make my wordpress site that is run by nginx on win 2012 r2 to use https on /cart/,/my-account/ and /checkout/ pages but all of the resources are loaded trough http and gives mixed content warning that results in page without css or js.

I tried changing in the wordpress settings -> general site address and worpdress address to https from http but that didnt help either. Now the whole site tries to load in https (which i don't need
Also i have surfed good amount in google and all kinds of tutorials on how to set up nginx with ssl but those mainly cover whole site ssl or just path that is not actually wordpress.

In my dev environment im using self signed ssl and it seems to be working for non wordpress pages (just plain html files). When testing on production server with purchased ssl cert it is working as well.

**So my question is** *can i set wordpress+nginx to serve one or few pages with https and rest of the wordpress pages to be served as http ( including css ,js and images)?*

I have set 2 server blocks, each for http and https. I also have set phpmyadmin and jwplayer selfhosted js library server blocks to be able to play wowza streams. The site is running smooth just with http and there is no problems so far.

My full nginx configuration 
https://pastebin.com/2ZzmDgDR

Below is the code from self-siged-ssl.conf

```
# from https://cipherli.st/
# and https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_nginx.html

ssl_certificate C:/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key C:/nginx/ssl/server.key;


ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_tickets off;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 5s;
# Disable preloading HSTS for now.  You can use the commented out header line that includes
# the "preload" directive if you understand the implications.
#add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

# ssl_dhparam C:/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
```

Comment: Why not just make the world a better place and run the whole site on HTTPS. Running just part of your site this way gives a false sense of security as it invites cross site scripting and gains you nothing.

Comment: hmm you might be right. The idea was to not deal with all the http->https conversion and adjusting the other parts of the system to work with https. Instead only port payment pages and login to https. I guess i just have to go the long way and make the whole site https.

Comment: If you configure https properly the work to be done should not increase by the amount of pages anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing HTTP and HTTPS is a **very** uncommon approach. That's why *the wordpress configuration does not offer it* and restricts you to either HTTP **or** HTTPS.

If you load thirdparty sources over HTTP on your ssl-encrypted website, try switching the thirdparty-sources to HTTPS. If that's not possible move the sources to your webspace to have it being loaded over HTTPS - which you should always consider regarding pagespeed.

Is there anything that prevents you from loading the resources over HTTPS?

Comment: probably offtopic but the only thing now not working is the jwplayer distro, it is still distributed as http with the following code 
`
     server{
        listen 2000;
        server_name www.mysite.dev mysite.dev;
          root C:/xampp/htdocs/jwplayer7/;
            location /system/misc/jwplayer7/ {
              alias "C:/xampp/htdocs/jwplayer7/";
              autoindex on;
            }     
    }
`
It is not possible to have HTTPS over port 2000?

Comment: This barely code snippet looks like jwplayer is hosting a service on your server on Port 2000. I don't think changing the port 2000 to 443 in *this* config would fix the problem anyways. To get rid of the *mixed content warning* it is important where and how parts of this jwplayer are included **on** the website itself. You can track the actual resource being included in chrome's dev-tools' network-tab. I can't imagine that jwplayer won't work properly on HTTPS sites, therefor I pressume there must be some way of configuring it. Have you enabled HTTPS in the very main wordpress-config?

Comment: i managed to find a workaround for serving jwplayer code, but now im left with the problem of jwplayer not fetching http playlist over https. I guess this is browser constraints and i have to configure wowza to serve a https link playlist.